# Core Plot padding left making some part of graph invisible while scrolling left

Tags: core-plot

When I try to scroll left of the axis, the x-axis is invisible to some extent because of setting left padding. Could someone help me on it ?

"This is the actual graph initially"

[image: This is the actual graph initially]

"This is when scrolled to left"

[image: This is when scrolled to left]

Same image with red circle identify the spot of the issue

[image: Same image with red circle identify the spot of the issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `axisConstraints` to fix the axis in place even when scrolling the graph.

```
y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
```